# add_edge in igraph resulting in self-loop instead of new edge

Tags: python, igraph, edges

I have two different graphs: g1 and g2. I want do add them together and create some edges. Why this does not work?

```
import igraph

def edging_up(g1, g2):
    g = g1 + g2
    for v in g.vs:
        for w in g.vs:
            try:
                if v['name'].get_researcher_id() == w['name'].get_tutor_id():
                    g.add_edge(v, w)
            except:
                pass

    return g
```

I need the try/exception because one graph does not have the get_tutor_id() method.
I also tried

```
def edging_up(g1, g2):
    g = g1 + g2
    for v in g1.vs:
        for w in g2.vs:
            if v['name'].get_researcher_id() == w['name'].get_tutor_id():
                    g.add_edge(v, w)
    return g
```

Then, it works, but instead of adding an edge from v to w, it adds a self-loop to v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example does not work because `w` is a vertex from `g2`, and you are trying to add an edge in `g`. The vertex objects that igraph returns are actually simply proxies to vertex indices , so when you run `g.add_edge(v, w)`, igraph will simply retrieve the `index` attribute of `v` and `w` and then essentially run `g.add_edge(v.index, w.index)`, which does not make sense in the context of `g` (because the indices refer to `g1` and `g2`, respectively).

As for the first example, you need to provide more information; for instance, what does the `name` vertex attribute contain?

Comment: `'name'` contains all the methods of the python class object that I added. I also found out (a lot of thinking since yesterday), that when I add two graphs (that are not identical) I lose all of the attributes (such as `'name'`). And I could not find many answers/help on the web. They are mostly about igraph in R. Should I try networkx? Thanks,

Comment: As I understood it, 'name' maintains the node as a python object with access to all its original methods and variables, right?

Comment: I mean, in example 2, I debug and I found that the conditional clause is correctely checked. Just the add_edge bit is faulty!

Comment: As I said, example 2 is faulty because you are adding an edge to `g` based on vertices that come from `g1` and `g2` - this won't work. As for the first example, the problem is probably that the `name` attribute is indeed lost when you are adding two graphs together - unfortunately vertex attributes do not "survive" the addition operator yet. You have to add the attributes manually as well: `g.vs["name"] = g1.vs["name"] + g2.vs["name"]`.